# Can’t connect to internet via iPhone with IOS 12.3.1 when using USB tethering

Tags: arch-linux, iphone, tethering

I am a Arch Linux user. I connect my iPhone to the computer with a USB cable. I successfully pair my phone using `idevicepair pair` command, however there is no internet connection. My iOS version is 12.3.1. How can I investigate the issue?

FWIW, I successfully tethered using the `ip link` command.

First I found the interface name of iPhone using:

```
ip link
```

Then enabled the interface by using:

```
ip link set interface up
```

After that iPhone is tethered when I connect it via USB. However this iPhone that I tested is another iPhone not mine. I still can't tether to my iPhone.

I can't even connect to it using Wi-Fi. My network manager [Wicd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wicd) gets stuck at “obtaining ip address” when I try to connect to its Wi-Fi hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem is related to the APN settings for the hotspot. Following the steps in this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/340479) solved the problem.